# Problem in an example to Radon-Nikodym theorem.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variable with a joint distribution $P_{(X,Y)}$ absolute continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$.
 I want to show that  **$P_{(X,Y)}$  has a density**, that it, there exists a measurable function $f_{(X;Y)}$:$\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$   such that $E\left ( g(X,Y) \right )=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}g(x,y)f_{(X，Y)}(x,y)$ for every positive measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow[0,\infty[$.
Question: What is the relation between this example and Radon-Nikodym theorem?

Comment: That is the [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem). Do you want to do that yourself? It looks a bit like reïnventing the wheel.

Comment: @ drhab Thank you for your comment. But I couldn't derive probability density from Radon-Nikodyn theorem. Please write it for me.

Comment: I am not able to write it out more clearly than in the link in my former comment. A measurable function $f$ exists such that $P_{X,Y}(A)=\int_A fd\lambda$. This $f$ is the [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Formal_definition) you are looking for. Is it your question how to prove that $\mathbb Eg(X,Y)=\int gfd\lambda$ for each suited $g$? If so then you asked the wrong question.

Comment: @drhab thank you so much for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the Radon-Nikodym theorem we need that:

(1) $P_{(X,Y)} \mbox{ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure}$ $\lambda^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$

(2) $P_{(X,Y)}$ is $\sigma-$finite which is satisfied since it is even finite: $P_{(X,Y)}(\mathbb{R}^2) = 1 < \infty$.

(3) The Lebesgue measure $\lambda^2$ is $\sigma-$finite, for this we define for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the set $B_n := [-n,n] \times [-n,n]$ then we clearly have that $B_n \nearrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and for each $n: \lambda^2(B_n) = 4n^2 < \infty$. From this we conclude that $\lambda^2$ is indeed $\sigma-$finite.

Now the Radon-Nikodym theorem yields that there exists a measurable function $f_{(X,Y)}: X \rightarrow [0,\infty[$ which satisfies that what you need if you use Proposition 4.1 in the following:
https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/4-04-rn.pdf

Comment: This is the complete answer, thank you. I ll add the complement for the last part.